# Core data is not persisting in IOS

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm having an issue where my core data does not persist *sometimes*. This is the scenario I'm running. I run the app when I'm not logged in, login, and the app stores some data. I then run the app again, this time as the logged in user, and pull that data. It was all working well until I tried to run the app as if it had been downloaded for the first time. To do this I deleted the app from my phone and ran the above steps. However now no data is pulled from the Core Data. Here are some interesting notes and things I have done to remedy the situations.

1) I know with 100% certainty that the data persists if the app is **not** being run as if just downloaded.

2) The data occasionally persists when run as if just downloaded, but the minority of the time.

3) When I run the app as if just downloaded and store the data into the Core Data, I do an immediate check to see if the data was stored *and it is*. When I run it again, however, the data is gone.

I'm refraining from posting code right now just because it's very large and would take a lot of time to shorten for the sake of posting. However if you think it'll be helpful in light of what I have said I will post it.

Comment: At what point do you save your Core Data context?

Comment: Once I'm done creating my entities I manually save it. I use the                 [document saveToURL:forSaveOperation] function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that you save with `[document saveToURL:forSaveOperation]`.

In order to persist Core Data you have to save the context.

```
[managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Make sure you call this with a valid context before you expect your data to be persisted. I suspect you have this in some places but not in all required places. One way to find out is to put a breakpoint on *each* save statement and check if the saves are called as expected.

Comment: Is it still proper to call both? Should I call one within the completion handler of the other?

Comment: I think you do not have to call save on the document. If the persistent store is wrapped in a `NSManagedDocument`, everything should be automatic.